# grunt-rev with images in javascript source?

Tags: javascript, image, gruntjs, revisions

I'm assigning a few pictures in JavaScript:

```
if(retina) {
  images.src = '../images/screen2@2x.png';
} else {
  images.src = '../images/screen2.png';
}
```

How can I tell grunt-rev to change those paths as it does with the images assigned in the CSS files? In this case it should result in something like `b511059b.screen2.png`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution, if you don't want to match some files, use `!` , for example: `'!images/*.png'`

Comment: See also related issue for grunt-min: https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/235